# How to delete an object from array with TTL and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete a token from tokens array in my users schema with TTL using mongoose,
When I use `createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, expireAt: { type: Date, default: undefined }` outside the array the document is deleted. 
But when I put these inside the array - nothing happens.

Hope you can help me with that, here is my code:

```
var UserSchema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tokens: [{
        access:{
            type: String,
                    required: true
        },
        token:{
            type: String,
                    required: true,
        },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        expireAt: { type: Date, default: undefined }
    }]
});
UserSchema2.index({"expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 5 } );
```

here is the middleware where is save the document:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    var tokens = [];
    tokens.push({access: 'abc', token: 'myToken123', expireAt: new Date(req.query.date)});

    var user = new User2({
        email: 'example@gmail.com',
            tokens: tokens,
    })
    user.save().then( (doc) => {
        res.send(doc);
    }).catch( (err) => {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```